# Previous linux install is still listed as a boot option

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot

I decided to switch my windows 10 laptop to manjaro linux. After a few days I decided to try a different distro and switched to solus budgie. After that I decided to return to windows. When changing the boot priority to the windows live usb, Manjaro was still an option on the boot list and I don't know why. The computer in question is a lenovo 730s-13iwl if that matters at all. It is currently running windows 10.

Comment: Edit the grub2 bootloader: https://www.howtogeek.com/196655/how-to-configure-the-grub2-boot-loaders-settings/

Answer (score 0):

Open MSCONFIG from RUN and open the BOOT tab. You can remove it from there.

Select the Option you want to remove and click delete.

You can also select (add/remove) Advanced Boot Options and Set Defaults there as well.